# using template literal to assign value to title attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6

i need to assign the title attribute of a div which is creating using java-script
the issue i am facing is when the title includes multiple words separated by space the example code is

```
let value = "example value to display";
$("#parentDiv").append(`<div title=${value}> ${value}</div>`);
```

the result i am getting is

```
<div title="example" value to display> example value to display</div>
```

i am not sure what the issue is most probably the template literal is assuming that the space is the end of the string, anyone have a solution please help

Comment: I don't see a template literal in this entire post.

Comment: Template literals are enclosed with back ticks ``.

Comment: sorry about that but in stackoverflow when i am adding backticks it automatically detects as code

Comment: You need to use 4-space indentation on StackOverflow for code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes (`"` or `'`) around title value as your title value contains space.

```js
let value = "example value to display";
$("#parentDiv").append(`<div title="${value}"> ${value}</div>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parentDiv'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Attributes containing spaces or other non-alphanumeric characters must be enclosed with `"` or `'`:

```js
let value = "example value to display";
$("#parentDiv").append(`<div title="${value}"> ${value}</div>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv"></div>
```

But really, it's a bad idea to build HTML this way. jQuery has methods for setting elements' attributes and text. So go ahead and use them:

```js
let value = "example value to display";
$("#parentDiv").append($('<div>').attr('title', value).text(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv"></div>
```

Comment: +1 for using DOM methods (or jQuery). This will take care of proper escaping, unlike the template interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Your template is missing double quotes on your title attribute.

```
let value = "example value to display";
$("#parentDiv").append(`<div title="${value}"> ${value}</div>`);
```

Answer (score 1):

The result is `<div title=example value to display> example value to display</div>`. This is caused by the fact that there are no double quotes at all.

It should be instead:

```
$("#parentDiv").append(`<div title="${value}"> ${value}</div>`);
```

Comment: @HariGopal You can only choose one accepted answer, but you seem to be going along checking several answers. Please choose the one that you think answered your question the best.